# after_save callback with virtual attributes Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, after-save

I don't know if this is possible so I thought I would ask.

```
1. Give a model some virtual attributes
2. Assign values to the model and the virtual attributes
3. Save the model 
4. Use a callback after_save to create a different object with the virtual attributes.
```

Can this be done in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as associations are irrelevant for you, use:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/clone